Swing: JDialog not hidden when switching to another app in Mac OS
I have two problems using a JDialog inside of a JFrame in Mac OS. I think they are related so that's why I'm combining the question here.
In my app a have a main frame and several JDialogs. The JDialogs are not modal because I want the users to be able to work in the main JFrame while keeping the JDialogs open.
The parent of the JDialog is the JFrame.
The JDialog is always shown ontop of the JFrame, even if it's not active anymore, which is not ideal, but I guess this is how it is.
Problem #1
When the JDialog is still displayed but the underlying JFrame is active and the JFrame displays a JOptionPane, the JOptionPane is displayed over the JFrame but BELOW the JDialog.
(In this example by selecting the menu command "file - exit" or for example this could happen when quitting the application by command+q and the user is asked to save the changes)
This is not ideal and sometimes the JOptionPane is just behind the JDialog and cannot be seen.

Problem #2
If the user now switches to any another application, all windows of my app should be hidden, but the JDialog stays on the monitor. This even happens when closing the JOptionPane before.

Here attached is a sample code to run the problem:
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            TestFrame frame;
            frame = new TestFrame();
            frame.setTitle("frame");
            JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
            JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
            JMenuItem exitMenuItem = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Exit") {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int confirmToExit = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Confirm to exit");
                    if (confirmToExit == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            });
            fileMenu.add(exitMenuItem);
            menuBar.add(fileMenu);
            frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
            frame.setSize(600, 400);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            TestDialog dialog = new TestDialog(frame, false);
            dialog.setTitle("dialog");
            dialog.setSize(300, 200);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    static class TestFrame extends JFrame {
    }

    static class TestDialog extends JDialog {
        public TestDialog(Frame owner, boolean modal) {
            super(owner, modal);
        }
    }

}


Setting the owner of the JDialog to NULL is not an option, because the menu bar disappears in this context and it is not possible to have a mac-os-menubar in a JDialog.
